# "Joining" data from two observables into new "enriched"

Tags: typescript, rxjs6, angular13

I have two get requests which returns data like this.
First request (marriage data)

```
[{
  id: 1,
  hId: 2
}, {
  id: 6,
  hId: 1
}]
```

Second request:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Bob'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Billy'
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'John'
}]
```

What I want to achive with RxJs and observables:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Bob',
  married: true // we have object with hId === id
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Billy',
  married: true // we have object with hId === id
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'John',
  married: false 
}]
```

I'm doing it now with forkJoin -> but then I must iterate within map over responses[0] and filter/search out for within subjects. I feel like there is a better way of doing this with one of the rxjs magic operators/functions?

```
const joint = forkJoin([mariage, subjects]);
  return joint.pipe(
    map(responses => {
      responses[0].data.forEach((mItem) => {
        const found = responses[1].data.find((subj) => {
          return subj.id === mItem.hId;
        });
        mItem.married = found ? true : false;
      });
      console.log(responses[0].data);
      return responses[0].data;
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no magic rxjs operator that performs some kind of matching algorithm on arrays. To be honest your problem is not related to observables at all. Nevertheless I think you can write your code a little bite more concise using destructuring and mapping of your array to a new one:

```
forkJoin([subjects, marriage]).pipe(
  map( ([ subjectData, marriageData])  => 
    subjectData.data.map((mItem) => ({
      ...mItem,
      married: marriageData.data.some(item => item.hId === mItem.id)
    })
  ))
)
```